# Angular access in controller to ng-model in nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, controller, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have problem as in the topic. Using $parent in ng-model didn't help.
What I am trying to achieve is 2 clickable buttons to increase and decrease quantity field value by one and display summary (sum of each price*quantity) on the bottom of site.

```js
var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);
  app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.list1 = [
    { "uniqueId": "1", "name": "cat1" },
    { "uniqueId": "2", "name": "cat2" } 
  ];
  $scope.list2 = [
    { "uniqueId": "1", "name": "prod1", "price": "10" },
    { "uniqueId": "2", "name": "prod2", "price": "20" },
    { "uniqueId": "3", "name": "prod3", "price": "30" }
  ];
  
  // this one below doesn't work at all
  // $scope.quantity[1] = 1; 
  
  $scope.inc = inc;
    
  function inc(id) {
      console.log(id); //works fine
      // increase of exact quantity
  }
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table ng-repeat="l1 in list1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{l1.name}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="l2 in list2">
        <td>name: {{l2.name}},</td>
        <td>price: {{l2.price}},</td>
        <td>quantity wanted: <input ng-model="quantity[l2.uniqueId]"><button ng-click="inc(l2.uniqueId)" type="button">+</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    {{quantity}}<!-- sum of all quantities * prices -->


  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there is mulitple way to solve this kind of problem, here is the grand line I see to do it and an example for each step:

- Store your quantity somewhere and initialise it, for example in your product object, example in your controller:

  `{ "uniqueId": "1", "name": "prod1", "price": "10", quantity : 1 },`
- Create a function to increase and an other to decrease the quantity of a product by his id, example in your controller:

  `function increaseQuantity(id){
          // Get your product in the list with a loop
          // If the product exists
         // Increase his quantity
     }
     function decreaseQuantity(id){
         // Get your product in the list with a loop
         // If the product exists
         // Decrease his quantity
     }
     $scope.increaseQuantity = increaseQuantity;
     $scope.decreaseQuantity = decreaseQuantity;`
- Call the right methods in your buttons, example in your view:

  `<td>
      quantity wanted: {{l2.quantity}}
      <button ng-click="increaseQuantity(l2.uniqueId)" type="button">+</button>
      <button ng-click="decreaseQuantity(l2.uniqueId)" type="button">-</button>
  </td>`